# Distribution of Code Signing certificate - best practices?

Tags: security, certificate, code-signing

Distribution of Code Signing certificate - best practices?

Note: I'm an absolute newbie when it comes to code signing and software certificates. I've tried to search and read about how to solve our particular problem, but have found nothing resembling online.

Until now, code signing has not been an issue for us, as we are working on embedded systems, based on Windows, but where we deliver turn-key solutions.
Then our antivirus (which is mandatory!) took a dislike for several of our binaries (across all projects), and there appear to be no real pattern in what it dislikes. After weeks of talking with the vendor of the antivirus, we have found that the solution for us, is is that our developers have a folder excluded from scanning (used for building the software), and that we implement code signing, while having our certificate white-listed in the anti-virus application (used for limited in-house distribution and testing of our software).

So for now we will be employing code-signing, not for security, but simply to be allowed to do our work. The antivirus vendor has informed us that self-signed certificates can not be white-listed - even thought that would have made sense.

Our developers are located at five locations worldwide, and we are looking for the simplest possible solution for us to ensure they can all perform code-signing (as it will otherwise not be possible for them to test the code they build).

We hope some sort of certificate distribution is possible, perhaps even by using Active Directory?

In the not-too-distant future we will need to do code signing to actually validate our software security, so if we are using the distributed certificate, would it then still be "safe" to use for validation? I guess not - which makes me wonder if we could have two certificates, and sign with both? One certificate would then be distributed, and allow us to build and test, then other would be used for actually publishing.

We will probably go with an Microsoft Authenticode Certificate - unless there are good reasons not to.

However, as far as I can understand, Microsoft has since February 1st 2017, required a Hardware Security Module (HSM) to be used in the code-signing process - we hope that does not mean each developer need their own HSM in their computer!

So to sum up my questions:

1. For code-signing of Windows binaries, are a HSM certificate required, or are there other better alternatives (in this situation).
2. What options are there to distribute a certificate among developers? Using AD would be nice, as it's already in place globally.
3. In a distributed setup, would it be possible to keep the signing certificate a secret?
4. Would double signing be an option to increase security? (One signing to beat the antivirus while testing, another for actual security of the released software)
5. Do you have a better solution for us to consider?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> For code-signing of Windows binaries, are a HSM certificate required, or are there other better alternatives (in this situation).

A Hardware Security Module (HSM) is just a hardware tool for doing cryptographic
operations such as key management, key exchange, encryption, verification and
safe-keeping.
There is no such thing as an HSM certificate, but there are certificates
generated by an HSM.

I have not myself used an HSM, but I would be wary of keys that are generated
by such hardware. They might be fine for internal use, but for external use
you must use certificates created by a well-know Certificate Authority (CA).

[Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is a free CA that is widely
used. In my organization we preferred paying for a well-known CA
for distributing our software.

> What options are there to distribute a certificate among developers? Using AD would be nice, as it's already in place globally.

You may use AD, but this might be an overkill for just a few programmers.
I would only use it for the development certificate, while keeping the
publishing certificate very secure, perhaps itself inside an encrypted container,
and under the full and unshared control of only one trusted person
(and possibly one backup person).

For more information see:

- [Distribute Certificates to Client Computers by Using Group Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/distribute-certificates-to-client-computers-by-using-group-policy)
- [How to deploy signing certificates to client computers using GPO?](https://www.manageengine.com/sccm-third-party-patch-management/kb/deploy-signing-certificates-using-gpo-how-to.html)

> In a distributed setup, would it be possible to keep the signing certificate a secret?

No, the moment that a secret is shared, it is no longer a secret.
Keep the distribution certificate very secure as above.

If it ever leaks, your certificate will be black-listed by all browsers
and anti-virus products, to the effect that all your distributed software
will become unusable.
Keep it secure as if your life depended upon it (at least your commercial life).

> Would double signing be an option to increase security? (One signing to beat the antivirus while testing, another for actual security of the released software)

Certainly, and I would see it as your only possibility.
The development certificate may leak, but you wouldn't care,
since the people who would leak it are also the ones capable of leaking
the unsigned modules.

> Do you have a better solution for us to consider?

Seems like you have thought deeply about the subject.
In your situation I would have also gone myself for such a
double-certificate solution.